# Apache - How to disable gzip content encoding (eg DEFLATE) for one set of URLs?

Tags: apache-2.2, gzip, mod-deflate, deflate

I have a ubuntu apache webserver and I have enabled [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html) to gzip all the content. However there's one folder I'd like to disable the mod_deflate for. I was going to do something like this:

```
<Location /myfolder>
   RemoveOutputFilter DEFLATE
</Location>
```

But that doesn't work.

---

**Rational:** I am trying to debug an XMLRPC server and I am using wireshark to see what gets past in the HTTP requests, since the replies are gzipped, I can't see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that RemoveOutputFilter expects a file extension, not a filter type.  It should be something like:

```
<Location /myfolder>
      RemoveOutputFilter html 
</Location>
```

or whatever file extension you're using in that directory.

Comment: One look at the documentation of mod_mime (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#removeoutputfilter) and you'd know rather than only believe that `RemoveOutputFilter` expects one or more file extensions as argument. ;)

Comment: In this case `RemoveOutputFilter text/html` would be correct

Answer (score 0):

@rvf, thanks for the help!

I was struggling with downloading of desktop (not html, css or js) files being corrupted during download but only for some users.  Internet Explorer had the most trouble. The problem was that the server's GZIP was compressing already compressed ZIP files and other files that needed to be unmodified binary transfers including PDF, DWG and SKP.  I thought those files had been removed from the compression but found out they were still being compressed using this online gzip test tool

http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php

Comment: IE is notorious for not handling this situation correctly. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241822/why-is-gzip-compression-with-internet-explorer-not-working